# How to pass value from database to jquery datepicker to open an Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I need to open alert when a person selects certain date. The contents of the alert should come from a database, and not only display the date he clicked (like a calendar of events). I can already display the alert normally, but have no idea how to call the contents of the database. the database is in SQL. Can anyone help?

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        }
    });
  });
  </script>  



<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

    <div id="datepicker"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            displayEvts(dateText);
        }
    });
  });

function displayEvts(dateText) {
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/getEvts/',
             dataType: 'json',
            success: function(evts) {
                alert(evts);
            },
            data: {'date':dateText,},
            async: false
        });
}
```

Something like this is probably what you want. Of course you need to implement the web-service for getEvts/ as Robert mentioned.
p.s.: I'm using jquery to make the AJAX Call

Answer (score 1):

You will have to build a webservice that takes a date, queries the database, and returns the detailed data.  A more detailed description is beyond the scope of what you'll get here without posting a more specific question about which aspect you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access SQL Server from JavaScript. You will have to fire an ajax call to a web service [which can be in .net/jsp/php] along with required parameters and then fire a query to your database. Your web service can then simply print the output of select query which you can capture in ajax call handler.

Here are couple of examples to get you started:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html

Good luck!